# ruby の並列処理は、仕様としてどう実現されている?

Tags: ruby, マルチスレッド

C++ や Java は、その並列処理についてひたすら複雑な仕様書があったと記憶しています。翻って ruby はどうだったか、と疑問に思いました。

質問:

- ruby の並列処理の仕様は定義されていますか? 定義されている場合、それはどこに資料としてまとまっていますか?

Comment: 次の投稿の回答はとても参考になりました: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/ruby%E3%81%AE%E7%B5%84%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%81%8B%E5%90%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby リファレンスマニュアルの [スレッド](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.5.0/doc/spec=2fthread.html) ではないでしょうか（バージョンによるリンク切れ時は [プログラミング言語 Ruby リファレンスマニュアル](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja) から辿りましょう）。

> ### スケジューリング
>
> Ruby のスレッドスケジューリングはネイティブスレッドのそれを利用しています。 よって詳細はプラットフォームに依存します。

スレッドについては [`Thread` クラスのリファレンス](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.5.0/class/Thread.html) を参照します。